# How to center this buttons on the topbar on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I need your help to make the top navigation bar responsive like this:

[image: Screenshot showing the desired result.]

I would like to make these buttons centered on mobile.

Comment: Please show your code. Edit your question and show your HTML and CSS so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to achieve this effect.

Example:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

a {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">item</a>
  <a href="#">item</a>
  <a href="#">item</a>
</nav>
```

---

If you want to apply this **only** on mobile devices you can use the `@media` queries. (Try resizing your browser window down to notice the change.)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    a {
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">item</a>
  <a href="#">item</a>
  <a href="#">item</a>
</nav>
```